# How to get text content of a clicked element with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a bunch of buttons and I want when I click on any of them get the `innerText` of the clicked element how I can do that with React.

In this example the code will work only with first button cause I put the value attribute.

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button value={"buttonOne"} onClick={handleButtonClick}>buttonOne</button>
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>buttonTwo</button>
      </div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Use `.innerText` instead of `.value`

Comment: Yes, as @mousetail says, you should use either `e.target.innerText` or `e.target.textContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.innerText` to get the "text" of the button. Alternatively you can use `element.innerHTML` or `element.textContent`.

```js
const { useState, Fragment } = React;

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button value={"buttonOne"} onClick={handleButtonClick}>buttonOne</button>
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>buttonTwo</button>
      </div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

It should be noted that using these native DOM operations is usually an anti-pattern in React, for a declarative app it's ill advised to access content on the DOM imperatively. A better approach would be to use a store for your button contents and retrieve it from there.